# How to do through routing in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-2

Now I have some rules for routing in file CI `routes.php`:

```
$route['^fr/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^en/(.+)$'] = "$1";
```

It works when I use URL as:

```
http://test.com/en/news
```

But does not work for:

```
http://test.com/en/news/3
```

Or

```
 http://test.com/en/news/4/1/3/any
```

After there are a routing for news:

//NEWS

```
$route['news/search'] = "news/search";
$route['news/(:num)'] = "news/getNew/$1";
$route['news/category/(:num)/(:any)'] = "news/filter/$1";
$route['news/category/(:num)'] = "news/filter/$1";
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I tried that page is opened with URL `http://test.com/en/news/3` for my routing

Comment: Post your `News.php` controller too.

Comment: I have some routing rules after for `news` may be is it reason

Comment: Updated question with routing